# Inaccurate scipy minimize with bounds

Tags: python, scipy

I am very new to Python, and I try to minimize some function, but the result seems inaccurate, or at least the difference with the Matlab result is too big.

My two questions are: 
(1) Am I right to assume the difference in the results comes from an inaccurate Python solution? 
(I believe so because for example change(c1)/change(y1) is constant in Matlab as I believe it should be, while it changes quite a bit in Python.)

(2) What can I do to improve the accuracy of the Python result?

I have already tried other methods (TNC, L-BFGS-B), and providing an analytical gradient or more accurate numerical gradient, other routines (minimize_scalar with method='Bounded'), but they all give pretty much the same result.

## here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.optimize import Bounds

#need to define nu
def ut_fun(CC):
    if nu != 1:
        UU = (CC ** (1-nu) - 1) / (1-nu)
    else:
        UU = log(CC)                    
    return UU


#need to define RR, A1,y1,y2_L,y2_H,gamma,beta,bb
def obj_2per(c1):

    A2 = RR*A1 + y1 - c1

    c2_L = RR*A2 + y2_L
    U_L = ut_fun(c2_L)    
    c2_H = RR*A2 + y2_H
    U_H = ut_fun(c2_H)

    EV2 = gamma*U_L + (1-gamma)*U_H    
    mVV = - (ut_fun(c1) + beta*EV2)
    return mVV


nu      = 2
A1      = 0
bb      = 0
beta    = 0.96
RR      = 1/beta
y2_L    = 0.1
y2_H    = 0.2
gamma   = 0.5


#Pre-allocation in np arrays
y1_vec  = np.linspace(0.04,0.4,10)
c1_star  = np.zeros(len(y1_vec))

#Actual optimization:
c1_0 = 0.01

for ii in range(len(y1_vec)):
    y1      = y1_vec[ii]        
    ub      = RR*A1 + y1 - bb   
    bnds = [(-np.inf,ub)]    
    sol = minimize(obj_2per,c1_0,method='trust-constr', bounds=bnds)

    c1_star[ii]  = float(sol.x)        
    c1_0        = c1_star[ii];            

print(c1_star)
```

The Python result is:
[0.03999284 0.07995512 0.11997128
 0.14458588 0.16599669 0.18724888
 0.20837178 0.22939139 0.25032751 
0.27119543]

The Matlab result is:
0.0399997050892807  0.0799994508682207  0.119999719341015   0.153878407968280   0.174286891630529   0.194695468467231   0.215103764323911   0.235511996564921   0.255920191410148   0.276328383256344

The difference in results from the fourth entry onwards is too large.

Comment: Why would you expect the same solution? This is something which can rarely be guaranteed. Your are probably comparing different algorithms (and you are not tuning tolerances it seems) and therefore your results are likely to be different. Even simple array-summation is different (numpy more accurate than matlab imho). Also: comparing those result-vectors is pretty useless: check the constraints / bounds and then check the objectives: which one is more accurate (better objective while being feasible) is probably a better question then why is A outputting a different solution than B.

Comment: Thank you for your answer: I checked the function values, and it turned out there was an error in my Matlab code. So now both the Python and the Matlab algorithm with standard tolerances give practically the same answer.